# jquery call back not responding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, http-post

I made a script but the big problem I found even I did it many times is the call back of jquery not respond:

**Here the HTML CODE**

```
        <h2 class="form_new_project-heading">Please Add Your Information</h2>
    <label for="project_URL" class="sr-only">project url</label>
    <input type="text" id="project_URL" class="form-control" placeholder="url- http://www.host.com/folder/"  data-validation="url" required="" autofocus="">
    <label for="callback" class="sr-only">callback</label>
    <input type="text" id="callback" class="form-control" placeholder="callback url- http://www.host.com/folder/callpack.html" required="">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="registernewapp" type="submit">add new project</button>
```

**and here the jquery script code in the end of the page**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.47/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#registernewapp').click(function(){
  var a_data=$('#project_URL').val();
  var b_data=$('#callback').val();
  $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         data:{server:a_data,back:b_data}
         url:"http://localhost/",
         success: function(msg) {
         alert(Data);
         }
        });
});
```

```
<script src="http://localhost/ajax/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: http : // localhost/ what is this? I mean you try to passing your variable to where?? you should pass it to a file .. where is you file path? http : // localhost/  its not a file

Comment: yes i know and may link infact is  http://lovalhost/ajax/trojan/vip.php?add=newserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with the code:

This is likely not going to refer to a valid resource:

```
url:"http://localhost/",
```

So, change it to reference a page or php file or something.

Change the success function like this:

```
     success: function(msg) {
         alert(msg);
     }
```

But eventually you'll want to do more with the success function, especially since you're letting the user specify a callback function by name (which is not usually a good idea, btw).